# SQL query to Zend query builder (OR, AND, ORDER BY FIELD, IS NULL)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to change my SQL query:

```
SELECT link FROM shop_product_videos WHERE brand='Goddess' AND ( prodid='' OR prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL) 
ORDER BY FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid
LIMIT 1
```

This is what i tried so far:

```
    $query = $this->select('link')
                  ->from('shop_product_videos')
                  ->where('brand=?', $brand)
                  ->where('prodid=?', $prodid)
                  ->orWhere('prodid=""')
                  ->orWhere('prodid is null')
                  ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid)"))
                  ->limit(1)
                ;

    return   $this->getAdapter(false)->fetchAll($query);
```

but i keep getting errors:

> An error occurred
>
> Exception information:
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 1'
>   at line 2

Comment: var_dump($query) and see what did zend query builder made..

Comment: Try to take off the ) at the end of **prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid)**

Comment: @nacho but that closes this: `(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0)`

Comment: @Zeljka the output of this isn't clear. is there a cell i'm missing with the whole query?

Comment: @Rick Sanchez, i mean the last one, the one after the third prodid , so the whole line will be **order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid"))**

Comment: @nacho this is part of `new Zend_Db_Expr` ==== `->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid)"))`

Comment: @Rick Sanchez yes, but the problem it's that **the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 1' at line 2**, so you have a closing bracket more than you need. Your order clause should look like **ORDER BY FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid** and now is looking like **ORDER BY FIELD(prodid='' OR prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), prodid)**. Just try it

Comment: @nacho I see what you did here :).. 
I get a different msg now `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'brand' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: @Rick Sanchez Can you upload your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your query this way, i have modified the following the ) after the last prodid in the order by and i setted the name of the table before all columns names

```
$query = $this->select('link')
              ->from('shop_product_videos')
              ->where('shop_product_videos.brand=?', $brand)
              ->where('shop_product_videos.prodid=?', $prodid)
              ->orWhere('shop_product_videos.prodid=""')
              ->orWhere('shop_product_videos.prodid is null')
              ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(shop_product_videos.prodid='' OR shop_product_videos.prodid IS NULL, 1, 0), shop_product_videos.prodid"))
              ->limit(1)
            ;
```